# How to get top 10 records out of List (complex data type) based on categories?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a class structure:

```
class TopTenAccount{
    Long account;
    Long src;
    Long dest;
    Long count;
}
```

I have list of this object.

```
List<TopTenAccount> topTenAccount;
```

Now based on the counts i want top only 10 records(Criteria: "account+src+dest" should be same for each record).

Basically i want top 10 record for each category (account+src+dest).

Comment: Why don't you give us an example of what you want to do ?

Comment: i dont get your question. So you want top 10 records based on count?

Answer (score 1):

use Collections.sort with a custom comparator

```
                   Collections.sort(list,new Comapartor<TopTenAccount> {
      //override compateTo method with your compare logic

        });
```

Then make a loop and get the first 10 objects in this list

```
        for(int i=0;i<10 && i < list.size();i++) {
             System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: I understand sorting, but getting top 10 is what i am looking for with efficient way.

Comment: Collections.sort uses merge sort which has time complexity of O(nlogn) which is almost the best time we can have , then accessing the 10 top elements will take O(10), we can ignore that , so i believe this is a very efficient way.

Comment: Pls suggest some algo to get top n records, I have tried but end up writing bed code.

Comment: after sorting just iterate over the list and get the first 10 elements, its so simple

Comment: i need to get top 10 elements for field (account), and then again 10 for different account...so how do i verify while iterating if it is same or different account?

Comment: Please suggest some algos

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom sort, based on the count field. if thats what u need

```
topTenAccount.sort((x,y)=>{
int temp = x.count - y.count;
if(temp!=0)
return temp;
});
```

this will sort the collection based on *count* in ascending order. Next step is to do a loop and get the first/last 10 items in the collection.

Comment: @Amer..let's say if for some records 10 records are not available, then this will break, how can i handle that situation? I want minimum (1) and maximum 10 records.